# How to migrate my Nextcloud instance from one server to another?

Tags: nextcloud

Due to security reasons, I need to migrate my Nextcloud instance. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: What did you research for the moment?

Comment: no details/context, impossible to answer. Please give us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Nextcloud help in the article
[Migrating to a different server](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/migrating.html).

The main part of the migration is for the database to do
[Backup](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/backup.html)
on the old server, and
[Restoring backup](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/restore.html)
on the new server.

More can be found in the article, which you should follow exactly.